# How to create object by using normal editor?

Tags: django

in the beginning i want to apologize for my poor english
I want to create/add to datbase an object and the problem is that i want to do this in editor in my IDE.
for example:

```
class Word(models.Model):
text=models.CharField(max_length=20)
num=models.IntegerField(default=1)
author=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and when i try to create(by using `Word.objects.create(text="hello",author="john")` an object in file e.g `<models.py>`

Problem is that in my database object is double(in database are 2 the same objects)
Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?
(i know that i can add object to database in interactive terminal)

Comment: So you mean `Word.objects.create(..)` creates *two* objects? Did you override the `save(..)` function, or added a trigger?

Comment: no i only use comed `Word.objects.create(..)` but to be honest everthing which i write in file `models.pl` is double for example :  
when i write a loop in the file:  
`for ele in list:
print(ele)`   
and then use comend `py manage.py runserver` in terminal i see a result of 2 the same loops

Comment: I think you first better try to find out why that is happening, instead of trying to "circument" the problem. Even if you manage to get this working with an IDE/web service/..., then other problems will still persist.